# Configuring Oracle Db connection String in .net core using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core package

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB and query a stored procedure in that DB, but I fail to make a connection to the DB. Here is the connection string:

```
"ConnectionString": "data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=somehost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=somename)));user id=someuserid;proxy user id=somepuserid;password=somepass;Persist Security Info=true"
```

But I get this error when I try to open the connection:

```
ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you specified `proxy user id`, but didn't specify `Proxy Password`.

Try this (no proxy User ID)

```
"ConnectionString": "Data Source=//somehost:1521/somename;User ID=someuserid;Password=somepass;"
```

Comment: I tried with your approach but unfortunately it didn't work! Instead I removed the proxy user and added the proxy name to the procedure name and it started working.